# Links in spoilers aren't hidden

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, spoilers

An answer today caught my attention: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2185406/62967

Here's an image of what I see with Safari 10.0.3 (with Firefox 52.0 it's the same):

[image]

The link in the spoiler is not hidden. Here's the picture taken with the pointer hovering over the spoiler

[image]

Here's the relevant part of the source:

```
Can you explicitly write up the congruences?

>! See also [monogenic semigroups][1].

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_semigroup
```

---

A spoiler with a link follows. Can you see it?

> Spoiler [with link](http://nonexistent.url)

Comment: [Possibly related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18966/mathjax-color-fights-hidden-text-and-wins)

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, one can avoid using `\color`, but links are not under user's control. Anyway this is not related to MathJax. Not a big deal, but a bit annoying.

Comment: Yes. I'm just saying it might be the same (or a related) mechanism causing both.

Comment: This seems to be specific to this site, and I think is a genuine bug that is something to be fixed. It does not happen on [matheducators.se] (precisely its meta), while it does happen also on meta here. Further there is a [meta.se] post about visited links showing through spoilers, which was declared fixed https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256941/visited-links-within-spoilers-are-not-hidden-anymore

Comment: @quid Thanks for the investigation; I left a comment to the meta.stackexchange answer. That question seems to address a different problem related to *visited* links. I did not visit the link in this spoiler.

Comment: Yes. What I meant to convey with the meta.se link is to say that this *type* of problem seems to be something that gets fixed (as it did get fixed even in the more restrained scenario of an already visited link). While the MJ color thing got declared as 'by design'.

Comment: It seems the problem went away! At least for me. See the answer here and on main.

Comment: @quid I added a spoiler with an unvisited link (invalid, actually). It shows on my machine. A visited one is hidden, instead.

Comment: Thank you for tracking this down. It is actually the same here. I was mislead byvisiting the link, then doing something else, and then noticing the link being properly hidden and not making that connection. The info that it does not happen on MESE seems correct though. I double checked and a spoiler there hides visited and unvisited alike.

Comment: I see the same visible unvisited link in hidden text with Google Chrome 57.

Comment: One of my [most upvoted comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454892/does-the-inverse-of-the-matrix-always-rely-on-the-determinant-of-a-matrix/1454895#1454895) is about a floating link inside of a spoiler box. (Found with [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/27196/my-top-ranked-comments) SEDE query)

Answer (score 10):

I've gone an updated the CSS for spoilers - there was something overriding the spoiler CSS in this instance.

With you in the next build (rev.  2017.3.14.*)

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark it as accepted when the links will disappear. `;-)`

Comment: You should have put this inside a spoiler tag, with a link to your own answer. :(

Comment: @egreg: I advise you to hold off acceptance until Oded complies with my comment. But otherwise, the new version has been pushed.

Comment: A minor issue is still present: if I hover on the spoiler and click the link, the spoiler doesn't disappear when the pointer exits the area. Apart from this, visited and unvisited links behave as expected.